# Python using a class within a function and appending to a list

Tags: python, list, function, class

I am relatively new to Python and classes.

I want to create a Person object with characteristics such as `name`, `age` etc. I then want to append a number of different people objects to a list. I am having issues when referencing the class in a function as it is looking for arguments but doesn't seem to work when I put in arguments. `Line 13`.

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, computing, maths, english):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.computing = computing      
        self.maths = maths
        self.english = english


def getPeople(num): 
    people = []
    for i in range(num):
        newPerson = Person()
        newPerson.name = input("What is the persons name?: ")
        newPerson.age = input("What is the persons age?: ")
        newPerson.computing = input("What is the persons Computing score?: ")
        newPerson.maths = input("What is the persons Maths score?: ")
        newPerson.english = input("What is the persons English score?: ")

        people.append(newPerson)

    return people

getPeople(5)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\records.py", line 24, in <module>
    getPeople(5)
  File "C:\Users\srecords.py", line 13, in getPeople
    newPerson = Person()
TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'name', 'age', 'computing', 'maths', and 'english'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: You created the object without its class arguments, you will have to call the person object with `Person(name, age,..)`

Comment: you called Person() with no arguments, but that has five required arguments. You should post the error message, but I suspect it says something about missing 5 required positional arguments?

Answer (score 2):

You need to collect the arguments first, *then* pass them to `Person`.

```
def getPeople(num): 
    people = []
    for i in range(num):
        name = input("What is the persons name?: ")
        age = input("What is the persons age?: ")
        computing = input("What is the persons Computing score?: ")
        maths = input("What is the persons Maths score?: ")
        english = input("What is the persons English score?: ")

        people.append(Person(name, age, computing, maths, english))

    return people

people = getPeople(5)
```

Note that there is a good case for using a class method here.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, computing, maths, english):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.computing = computing      
        self.maths = maths
        self.english = english

    @classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        name = input("What is the persons name?: ")
        age = input("What is the persons age?: ")
        computing = input("What is the persons Computing score?: ")
        maths = input("What is the persons Maths score?: ")
        english = input("What is the persons English score?: ")
    
        return cls(name, age, computing, maths, english)


def getPeople(num): 
    return [Person.from_input() for _ in range(num)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added an init method for the class, so you need to pass all those variables as arguments when you call the `Person()` class. As an example:

```
name = input()
age = input()
....
new_person = Person(name, age, ...)
people.append(new_person)
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to the `__init__()` method specify the arguments you have to supply when you call `Person()` (except that `self` is passed automatically). So you need to pass all the attribute values there, not assign them after creating the person.

```
def getPeople(num): 
    people = []
    for i in range(num):
        name = input("What is the persons name?: ")
        age = input("What is the persons age?: ")
        computing = input("What is the persons Computing score?: ")
        maths = input("What is the persons Maths score?: ")
        english = input("What is the persons English score?: ")
        newPerson = Person(name, age, computing, maths, english)

        people.append(newPerson)

    return people
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to collect the arguments first and then supply them to the new instance?

```py
def getPeople(num): 
    people = []
    for i in range(num):
        name = input("What is the persons name?: ")
        age = input("What is the persons age?: ")
        computing = input("What is the persons Computing score?: ")
        maths = input("What is the persons Maths score?: ")
        english = input("What is the persons English score?: ")

        people.append(Person(name, age, computing, maths, english))

    return people
```